# Bind and run a Python module with singularity from a remote directory

Tags: python, singularity-container

I need to run a personnal Python module from a singularity container.
I usually run it with the following command :

```
singularity run ./Image/myimage.sif -m mymodule.start
```

However it's only work if I am in the same folder as 'mymodule'.

Now, I need to run this same module from a remote directory. I therefore bind my 'mymodule' directory :

```
singularity run --bind ~/Projects/MyModule/:/mnt ./Image/myimage.sif -m mymodule.start
```

Unfortunately it is binded in the /mnt directory, which means my module cannot be found.
The error is

> /usr/bin/python3: No module named mymodule.start

How could I make mymodule findable ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends how the paths are specified in `module.start` but this should work with `apptainer`:

```
APPTAINERENV_PREPEND_PATH=$HOME/Projects/MyModule/ --bind ~/Projects/MyModule/:/mnt ./Image/myimage.sif -m mymodule.start
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally used the follwing command :

```
singularity run --bind ~/Projects/MyModule/:$HOME ./Image/myimage.sif -m mymodule.start
```

to mount my project in the home directory and have access to it without changing the directory.